# Develop a WebService in Visual Studio C#, and calling it from a separate VS Solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, testing

I am developed an app in Visual Studio C#.  The app is done.  Now I want to convert the app to a web service to be called by other apps in our very large network installation.  I am at the stage where I am learning to use web service.  So far, I have a simple HelloWorldToken type web app in a web service Solution.

> public WebService()
>       {
>       }

```
[WebMethod]
public string HelloWorld()
{
    return "Hello World - invoke me";
}

[WebMethod]
public string webServiceAdd(int a, int b)
{
    int c = a + b;
    return " " + a + " + " + b + " = " + c;
}

[WebMethod]
public string HelloWorldToken(string Token)
{
    return "Hello World authToken = " + Token ;
}
```

This works when I call it from the Visual Studio environment, and also works from an HTML web page.  The "action" tag calls the web service, and there are hidden fields in the form that contain the values to be passed.

```
     <form target="_blank" 
  action=http://localhost:51090/WebService.asmx/webServiceAdd
  method="POST">       
<tr>
    <td>
        Invoke Web Service <br />(from form)
        <input type="hidden" value="5" name="a" />
        <input type="hidden" value="4" name="b" />
        <input type="hidden" value="myUserName" name="usr" />
        <input type="hidden" value="myPassword" name="psw" />
        <input type="hidden" value="theToken" name="Token" />
    </td>
    <td align="left">
         <input type="submit" value="Invoke" class="button">
    </td>
</tr>
```

So far, so good.  The web page successfully calls the web service and the web service returns the value generated successfully.

However, ultimately I will need to call the web service from a separate C# application.  But to load the separate C# calling code, I must unload the web service code Solution.  When I unload the web service, it stops operating.  Any calls to it are not found.

I don't have access to an IIS on my computer due to installation rules (very tight).  *Running Visual Studio 2017 Professional.*

**My request is to have the web service running on the Visual Studio internal server, while also testing a different Visual Studio C# application (in a different Solution) to call the web service.  Is this possible**?

Comment: Not 100% sure if it will work, but can you run 2 instances of Visual Studio and launch each of the apps (web and desktop) at the same time? Ultimately, if you are expected to program a web app, and a desktop app, have them interact with each other, and debug the whole lot, your IT manager must allow you to run IIS Express / IIS. Otherwise they're not giving you the tools necessary to do your job.

Comment: Johnathan - surprisingly, such a simple solution works!  You should add your solution as the Answer, and I will mark it as the answer.  Took me a half hour to write the question, and the solution took a minute.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run 2 instances of Visual Studio and launch each of the apps (web and desktop) at the same time.

Comment: Thanks - now I need to actually *call* the web service from the console app and console form app.  But that is a separate question.  Do you know of any existing StackOverflo questions on this?  The questions that I have found are exceedingly complex.  I like simple.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a local **IIS**, your only choice is:

1.- Mount your web service code in a new project
2.- Run that project and keep it running
3.- Copy the URL localhost:port... that is shown in browser
4.- Go to your second project and add new service reference and paste the url copy before
5.- You can now use your web service

Comment: Carl0s - would you kindly expand on the **"add new service reference"** for me, or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Someone in my shop here advised on a second answer.  That is to put both the web service project and the calling project in THE SAME SOLUTION.  There is a way of setting both projects to start when the Solution is opened.  That way, both are running at the same time.
Right click on the Solution properties, Startup Project, and you have a radio button for Multiple startup projects.  You can order it the way you want.